# what's the difference between ambientDependencies and regular dependecies in typings

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In the following typings.json file, what the difference between ambientDependencies(or globalDependencies) and regular dependencies:

```
{
  "ambientDependencies": {
    "es6-shim": "registry:dt/es6-shim#0.31.2+20160317120654",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160412134438",
    "jquery": "registry:dt/jquery#1.10.0+20160417213236"
  },
```

> "dependencies": { }, <--- what does this do?

```
}
```

`typings install <something> --save` will save to dependencies, but what does this mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

imagine you have two dependencies:

**package.json**

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "a": "1.0",
        "b": "2.0"
    }
}
```

Where the dependency tree looks like:

```
|-a@1.0
|-b@2.0
```

In this case, there would be no difference between having both of them as `globalDependencies` or `dependencies`. 
However, an issue arises when they have their own dependencies. Imagine your dependency tree looks like this:

```
|-a@1.0
|  |-b@1.0
|  |-c@1.0
|-b@2.0
```

When you install `a@1.0` as a global dependency, it will strip references to `b@1.0` and `c@1.0`, and will ask you to install those dependencies as globals. It requires you to flatten your dependency tree to:

```
|-a@1.0
|-b@1.0
|-b@2.0
|-c@1.0
```

This works fine for `c@1.0`, but now you need two versions of `b`. `a@1.0` depends on `b@1.0`, but your app depends on `b@2.0`. Which type version do you install? If you install `b@2.0`, the type definitions for `a@1.0` might break. If you install `b@1.0`, your app types might break. This is the issue `globalDependencies` faces.

When you build a type definition using typings and install it as a regular dependency, it wraps up the sub-dependencies without exposing them to your app. This means that if you install `a@1.0` as a regular dependency, it won't use the top level `b@2.0` definitions. It will instead use its own private `b@1.0` that doesn't pollute your global namespace. Effectively, regular dependencies preserve your dependency tree structure, and they are the preferred way of approaching definitions. The issue is that not all libraries have type definitions built as regular dependencies. Ideally, as people write more definitions, globals will be naturally phased out.

Comment: Simple concise explanation. Cheers